# Obj-C - Drag cell from one tableview into another tableview?

Tags: ios, tableview

I have two `UITableViews` but they appear in the same `UIViewController`. That said, one acts as a reveal (slide out) side menu, and its code is housed inside `SideMenuViewController.h/.m`, and the other TableView is constantly visible in the ViewController.

I'm trying to make it so that I can long press on a cell in the side menu, and drag the selected cell into the TableView on ViewController.

Is this do-able? I've been searching high and low for tutorials, but this doesn't seem like a common ask. Open to all assistance.

Comment: It’s possible using the drag and drop features of UITableView. See the associated reference docs and then search on those protocols for examples and tutorials.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks! I searched the documentation on Apple, but they only seem to have the samples in Swift? Any idea where I can find it in Obj-c?